# Using BeanComparator to sort with mapped properties

Tags: java, comparator, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a List of objects with normal properties and a hashmap of custom field values and I'm trying to find a way to sort based on the value of a custom field in that map.

Example class:

```
class Result {

    int id;
    String name;
    Date date;

    Map customFields; 

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    etc....

    String getCustomField(String fieldId) {
        return customFields.get(fieldId);
    }

    public void setCustomField(String fieldId, Object value) {
        customFields.put(fieldId, value);
    }

}
```

Using a BeanComparator with "normal" properties the list sorts fine. But attempting with a mapped property gives me:

java.lang.RuntimeException: NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'customField'+ on bean class Result

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
ComparatorChain chain = new ComparatorChain();
chain.addComparator(new BeanComparator("customField(field99)"));

Collections.sort(results, chain);
```

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The issue is the Getter should return Object not String.